# spring cloud config : how to use multiple configs

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud-config

#### What I want to try:

I want to try the `spring cloud config` for microservice project where I have a `common config` for all services and `multiple configs` for each service.
I got idea on how to use multiple `profiles` using `spring.profiles.active` and `include`. I am trying to understand how can I load multiple configs on config client?

#### What I have:

In my git repo I have `spring-config-repo` where I have ...

```
application.yml
orderclient.yml
subscriberclient.yml
jmsclient.yml
productclient.yml
```

I have my `config Server` pointed to my config repo.

```
spring:
  application:
  name: config-service
  cloud:
   config:
    server:
      git:
        uri: https://github.com/<user>/spring-config-repo

server:
 port: 8888
```

I have my `spring client` where I want to use multiple configs. Here in my case for `orderService` I want to load `application.yml,orderclient.yml,jmsconfig.yml` and For Product microService I need 'orderconfig.yml,jmsclient.yml,productclient.yml'

```
spring:
application:
  name: orderclient
profiles:
  active: test
cloud:
  config:
    uri: http://localhost:8888

###Any kind of config properties to load jmsclient, productclient?
```

Above I can access properties from orderclient.yml.

### My Question:

#### Question1:

How to access properties of `jmsclient.yml,productclient.yml` in `orderclient` application.

#### Question2:

Is there anyway to get list of all `propertySources.name` exposed by config server? where in above case it should dispaly

```
"propertySources": {
  "name": "https://github.com/<>/spring-config-repo/aplication.yml",
     "profiles": <available profiles for this say> Dev, Test,
  "name": "https://github.com/<>/spring-config-repo/orderclient.yml",
     "profiles": <available profiles for this say> Dev, Test
  "name": "https://github.com/<>/spring-config-repo/jmsclient.yml",
     "profiles": <available profiles for this say> Dev, Test
 ....}
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear or need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

You can set a comma-separated list of configurations you want to load using `spring.cloud.config.name` property:

```
spring.cloud.config.name: jmsclient,productclient,orderclient
```

Comment: This did not work for me:
bootstrap: spring.cloud.config.name=redis,jobster

Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing: {"timestamp":1625003088090,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","message":"Cannot clone or checkout repository","path":"/redis,jobster/dev"}
Nothing in the docs either https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#_locating_remote_configuration_resources
Just that label can be comma delimited as a failover.